# AZure AD SAML Response in Angular Applicaiton

Tags: saml

We have a SPA and Web API

One of our client we are implementing SSO (Azure AD).

In Azure AD redirects SAML Response in POST. We are able to receive response in API Method.

But in our case we want to receive SAML in SPA. Then Send Response to our `/Token` Method to get actual token.

When Azure redirect to our SPA (i have added a html file , `redirect.html`)
it throws 405. I can see SAML response in DOM . But browser stops this request. It's bacause of web dal.

How to fix this issue?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

By adding .shtml instead of .html solves the 405 issue.

Another question is i am not able to read the data in jas